# Defining Custom Location aliases

Tags: directory, alias

I'm trying to find a way to access a directory without specifying the whole path each time.
For example, i download a lot of videos and I've set up a folder to store all those videos, since I'll be accessing and moving/copying stuff to and from that same folder many times and in many different occasions, I was looking for a way to define an alias (or something similar) that would allow me to refer to that folder quickly in the terminal, something on the likes of

```
mv video.mp4 VIDFOLDER
```

where

```
VIDFOLDER=/path/to/my/folder
```

As of now i tried only setting up an env variable, but it doesn't seem to work.
I tried looking for other way of doing it but haven't been able to find much.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are almost there:

Instead of `mv video.mp4 VIDFOLDER` you need to `mv video.mp4 "$VIDFOLDER"`.  The `$` is needed to use the variable.  It must NOT be used during assignement of the variable.

`export VIDFOLDER=/path/to/my/folder` should go into your `.bashrc`-file.

As an alternative, you could set up function for that (in `.bashrc` or `.bash_aliases`), see the [function provided by cas](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/541584/364705)

Comment: To set the variable as environment variable (make it available to child processes), you may want to [export](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/export.html) it like `export VIDFOLDER=/path/to/my/folder`.

Comment: Uhmmm, i might have found the problem. I defined the environmental variable using quotes as in 

    export VIDFOLDER="path/to/folder"

problem is i have to escape a space in the path, does it work even without quotes?

Comment: why not just `vidmv () { command mv "$@" /path/to/my/folder; }` and let `mv` handle any missing or unreadable file errors?  That also has the advantage of supporting **all** of the existing `mv` options (except `-T` which wouldn't work).   Or  `vidmv () { command mv "$@" "$VIDFOLDER"; }` allowing the OP to change the destination without redefining the function.   Of course, VIDFOLDER would have to be pre-defined in the shell or .bashrc.

Comment: @WhiteEyeTree You need to escape the spaces: `VIDFOLDER=temp/path\ with\ spaces/` and then you can `ls -l "$VIDFOLDER"`

Comment: or `vidls () { ls "$@" "$VIDFOLDER" ; }`    :-)   (I didn't use `command` here because people often have `ls` aliased to suit their output preferences.  The "$@" in the function allows adding more `ls` options to those prefs.)

Comment: @markgraf after tinkering a bit i managed to make it work. I never get the escapes/quotes the first time, i think i'll give up understanding what to quote, where and why ahahah

Comment: `VIDFOLDER="temp/path with spaces/"` should work, too.

Answer (score 2):

```
vidmv () { command mv "$@" /path/to/my/folder; }
```

`mv` would handle any missing or unreadable file errors as it normally does. This also has the advantage of supporting all of the existing `mv` options (except `-T` which wouldn't work).   e.g. `-v` for verbose, `-n` for no-clobber, `-u` for update-only, etc.

run as, for example:

```
vidmv -v -u *.mp4
```

Note: the `command` in the function runs `mv` as found in the PATH, ignoring any aliases or functions named `mv`.  For example, it's a common practice to `alias mv='mv -i'` -- this function would ignore that and run `mv` without `-i` unless you specified it as a `vidmv` option.

Or

```
vidmv () { command mv "$@" "$VIDFOLDER"; }
```

This version allows changing the destination without redefining the function. Of course, `VIDFOLDER` would have to be pre-defined in the current shell or `.bash_profile`, `.bashrc`/etc

Comment: Thanks for introducing me to the "$@" placeholder!
So many possibilities!
Anyhow, thanks for the alternate solution but in this particular case i wasn't looking for a customized command.
I might use it to quickly access configuration files, like cfgvim or something like that!

Comment: you're welcome. it's a bit of an eye-opener when you first start to realise the possibilities of writing your own little scripts and functions. i think the appropriate phrase is "first taste is free" :)